# Footer Suppression

Tags: header-footer, footnotes, conditionals

I'm wondering if it's possible to suppress footers if the page has a footnote, but display the footer as normal otherwise. To be specific, I'm reproducing an old book which uses catchwords for pages without footnotes, so I am using the `\NextWordBox` macro from the `fwlw` package inside my footer. Thanks all and have a great Christmas.

EDIT: The solution provided by ADP works except for cases where the word with the footnote is the first word of a page, in which case the previous page style is reset instead of the page with the footnote. Here's a MWE.

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[symbol,perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage{fwlw}
\makepagestyle{fn} %defines style when footnote is present
\makeevenhead{fn}{\thepage}{THE TWO NEW SCIENCES OF GALILEO}{}
\makeoddhead{fn}{}{\leftmark}{\thepage}
\makeoddfoot{fn}{}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{fn}{}{}{}
\makepagestyle{standard} %defines headings
\makeevenhead{standard}{\thepage}{THE TWO NEW SCIENCES OF GALILEO}{}
\makeoddhead{standard}{}{\leftmark}{\thepage}
\makeoddfoot{standard}{}{}{\usebox\NextWordBox}
\makeevenfoot{standard}{}{}{\usebox\NextWordBox}
\pagestyle{standard}
\newcommand{\myfootnote}[1]{%
    \footnote{#1}%
    \thispagestyle{fn}%change pagestyle for this page only.
}
\begin{document}
This is a sentence.
\newpage
This is another sentence.\myfootnote{This is a footnote}
\newpage
This is yet another sentence.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution using Fancyhdr Package.**

The method that comes to mind for me, is if you use the fancyhdr package, define two fancy page styles, one of pages where there are no footnotes, and one where there are.

Then by creating a new command for writing a footnote, which temporarily changes the page style, the output is achieved.

Here is a minimum working example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%Header and Footer.
\fancypagestyle{detailed}{
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
    \fancyhead[L]{LEFT HEADER}
    \fancyhead[R]{RIGHT HEADER}
    \fancyfoot[L]{LEFT FOOTER}
    \fancyfoot[R]{RIGHT FOOTER}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
}
\fancypagestyle{detailed_nofoot}{
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
    \fancyhead[L]{LEFT HEADER}
    \fancyhead[R]{RIGHT HEADER}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\newcommand{\myFootNote}[1]{
    \footnote{#1}
    \thispagestyle{detailed_nofoot} %change pagestyle for this page only.
}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{detailed}
    \section{Example With Footnotes}
    \lipsum[1-2]\myFootNote{First Footnote}\myFootNote{Second Footnote}
    \newpage
    \section{Example Without Footnotes}
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

**Bottom of page with footnotes present:**

[image: Footnote]

**Bottom of page without footnotes present:**

[image: No Footnote]

Comment: Sorry to bug you but I have noticed a small problem with this solution. It works perfectly except for cases where the word with the footnote is the first word of a page, in which case the previous page is set with the `detailed_nofoot` style instead of the page with the word.

Comment: Could you please post code for an example that creates the above error?

Comment: I have edited my post.